# The property String data is referenced by Visualforce Page (Chart) in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 3 column 19

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

I found this example to make a chart with visual-force but it gives the following

> error:The property String data is referenced by Visual-force Page (Chart) in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 3 column 19. Please explain this error.

Since I couldn't find an appropriate answer the code is below:

```
<apex:page controller="Chart">

    <apex:chart height="400" width="1000" data="{!data}">

    <apex:legend position="right"/>

    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left"  fields="data1" title="Side- A" grid="true"/>

    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="right" fields="data3" title="Side- B"/>

    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Side- C">

    <apex:chartLabel rotate="320"/>

    </apex:axis>

    <apex:barSeries title="A" orientation="vertical" axis="right" xField="name" yField="data3">

    <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>

    </apex:barSeries>

    <apex:lineSeries title="B" axis="left" xField="name" yField="data1" fill="true" markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="red"/>

    <apex:lineSeries title="C" axis="left" xField="name" yField="data2" markerType="circle" markerSize="4" markerFill="yellow"/>

    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code:**

```
public class Chart {// Return a list of data points for a chartpublic 
    List<Data>getData() {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

        data.add(new Data('A', 31, 40, 44));
        data.add(new Data('B', 44, 58, 83));
        data.add(new Data('C', 38, 82, 25));
        data.add(new Data('D', 74, 48, 85));
        data.add(new Data('E', 39, 20, 93));
        data.add(new Data('F', 33, 57, 99));
        data.add(new Data('G', 92, 03, 60));
        data.add(new Data('H', 87, 73, 45));
        data.add(new Data('I', 34, 65, 28));
        data.add(new Data('J', 78, 66, 56));
        data.add(new Data('K', 85, 67, 83));
        data.add(new Data('L', 29, 57, 85));
        data.add(new Data('M', 74, 57, 85));
        data.add(new Data('N', 57, 85, 95));
        data.add(new Data('O', 77, 56, 74));
        return data;

    }

    // Wrapper class
    public class Data {

        public String name { get; set; }
        public Integer data1 { get; set; }
        public Integer data2 { get; set; }
        public Integer data3 { get; set; }

        public Data(String name, Integer data1, Integer data2, Integer data3) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data1 = data1;
            this.data2 = data2;
            this.data3 = data3;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the signature of your method for `getData()`. Since you haven't use access modifier, the method is not visible from your VF page. Add access modifier as `public` to your method definition. Refer below code:

```
    public List<Data>getData() {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

        data.add(new Data('A', 31, 40, 44));
        data.add(new Data('B', 44, 58, 83));
        data.add(new Data('C', 38, 82, 25));
        data.add(new Data('D', 74, 48, 85));
        data.add(new Data('E', 39, 20, 93));
        data.add(new Data('F', 33, 57, 99));
        data.add(new Data('G', 92, 03, 60));
        data.add(new Data('H', 87, 73, 45));
        data.add(new Data('I', 34, 65, 28));
        data.add(new Data('J', 78, 66, 56));
        data.add(new Data('K', 85, 67, 83));
        data.add(new Data('L', 29, 57, 85));
        data.add(new Data('M', 74, 57, 85));
        data.add(new Data('N', 57, 85, 95));
        data.add(new Data('O', 77, 56, 74));
        return data;

    }
```

This is how your chart looks:

[image]